# Indulge/gratify my curiosity?

Tags: connotations

I understand that indulge and gratify have similar meanings but what are the differnces in connotations of these words in this sentences?

Indulge my curiosity

Or gratify my curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Indulge my curiosity* figuratively indicates that your curiosity wants to know something it doesn't really need to know.

*Gratify my curiosity* figuratively indicates that it will feel thankful when it learns the thing it wants to know.

Both are figurative because **curiosity** itself is being personified in these phrases.